# ListView in ListFragment click to items

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I got a simple ListFragment in my app to show static datas like Strings. I need to make list items clickable with Single Choice. Here it is what i tried so far. I can see list items but i am not able to get any logs from clicking list items.
What's wrong with that code ?

```
public class SettingsTab extends ListFragment implements OnItemClickListener{
String[] numbers={"one","two","three","four"};
ListView list ;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Settings tab", "Fragment Created (onCreate)");
    }
 @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Settings tab", "Fragment Created (onActivityCreate)");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingsfragment, container, false);
        list = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.listitemlayout,
                R.id.listitemUniName, names));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        Log.d("Settings tab", "Fragment Created (onCreateView)");
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Item clicked: " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("settings", "click worked");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

ListFragment is already a listener so do not set OnItemClickListener but override this method instead: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView, android.view.View, int, long).

Answer (score 1):

@Jukka Raanamo is right, this helped me, you can get rid of `OnItemClickListener` and method `onItemClick()`. Then override `onListItemClick()`.

For example:

```
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
       super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
       // Do whatever you need to do here.
       Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Item clicked: " + arg2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Log.d("settings", "click worked");
    }
```

Thanks @Jukka Raanamo